# forecasting two groups with prophet

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

Hello I am trying to forecast the following units per store and item

```
df.head()
ds  item    store   y
0   2019-01-13  A18-303 31  1.000
1   2021-02-21  104451-N04  3   2.000
2   2021-03-07  K231-G39    26  1.000
3   2021-01-10  K288-G39    26  -1.000
4   2019-06-30  A18-303 6   6.000
final = pd.DataFrame(columns=['item','store','ds','yhat'])    
grouped = df.groupby('store','item')
    for g in grouped.groups:
        group = grouped.get_group(g)
        m = Prophet()
        m.fit(group)
        future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=14)
        forecast = m.predict(future)
        forecast['item','store'] = g
        final = pd.concat([final, forecast], ignore_index=True)
```

My results are giving me NaN for all store and items.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not define the `final` dataframe properly.

The first time `pd.concat([final, forecast], ignore_index=True)` is run, `final` is still undefined so it will produce errors.

You can do the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['store','item'])
dfs =[]  # list of dataframes 
for g in grouped.groups:
    group = grouped.get_group(g)
    m = Prophet()
    m.fit(group)
    future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=14)
    forecast = m.predict(future)
    forecast['item','store'] = g
    dfs.append(forecast)
final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what I am putting as the list of data frames

Comment: @kmox I'm just appending the `forecast` dataframe as you do in your code. The only difference is that you cannot use 'final' to concat with itself before it is defined.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad I see I left out the line of code defining final. that said I am still unable to run with both store and item in the groupby

Comment: @knox you forget to add the two items as a list in groupby. Check my update.